# How to determine if HttpWebRequest exception originates from a proxy or a target server?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

While issuing HttpWebRequest using proxy I frequently get an exception, be it: TimeoutException, ServiceUnavailableException and similar.

An example:

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at ...

Examining the WebException and response (if exists) I check the properties WebException.Status and WebExceprion.Response.StatusCode and decide upon the action to take.
Example:

> WebException.Status: ProtocolError
> webException.Response.StatusCode: ServiceUnavailable
> webException.Response.StatusDescription: Service Unavailable

I create the request in a most basic way. Nothing special abou that:

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = Constants.USER_AGENT_CHROME;
    httpWebRequest.Proxy = webProxy;        // Proxy is being used!
    httpWebRequest.Timeout = HTTP_WEB_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS;


I use it something like this.


    try
    {
        request.getResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;
        switch (webException.Status)
        {
            case WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError:
                Trace.Assert(webException.Response != null, "webException.Response != null");
                switch (response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout:
                        Console.WriteLine("GATEWAY TIMEOT");
                        break;
                    case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                        return response;
                    case HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception();
                }
                break;
            case WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                Trace.Assert(webException.Response == null, "webException.Response == null");
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
     }
```

I just handle the things with respect to WebException.Status and in if a response exists HttpWebResponse.Status. But from this two I cannot deduce if the exception/error originates from proxy or from target server.
But this does not tell me anything if the error lies on proxy or the target server. And this would be useful to me.

So, how to determine if an error /exception originates from proxy or from target server?

Comment: The default proxy timeout is 30 seconds.  So if you get a 30 second timeout it is probably the proxy.  Setting proxy in the client to null usually solves the proxy issue.

Comment: How on earth could setting proxy to null solve the issue?

Comment: I've seen a lot of cases where a proxy was not needed and the Net library was looking for the proxy.

Comment: Well, the proxy is most certainly needed.

Comment: So you are getting an intermittent error?  Normally the credentials need to be verified against a password server and the authentiction is failing or timeing out.

Comment: @jdwenf No credentials, nu username, no password. Just plain proxy.

Comment: The proxy is checking network credentials.

Comment: Is there really nobody with a clue?